# Why Isn't this value copied on return?

Tags: c, variables, stack, return-value

I have a C function (in my Objective-C library, building in Xcode) that looks like this:

```
static uint32_t somelen() {
    char out[4];
    bzero(out, 4);
    // ... Work out contents of bytes 0-3.
    return *(uint32_t *)out
}
```

Works fine in debug mode, but but when built for release, the return value is sometimes completely wonky. I Now, I realize that `out` is created on the stack, so is cleaned up when the function exits. But I sure thought that, in the return statement, I was derefencing the value and returning a copy of the bytes. But apparently not. I can get the function to behave properly by making it a static variable:

```
    static char out[4];
```

But that seems silly. I only need that data for the duration of this function and the function that calls it. Returning a value that the calling function can store wherever it liks makes sense to me. How do I get it to do that?

Comment: `return *(uint32_t *)out` breaks the strict aliasing rule and therefore it is undefined behaviour. You should do something like `return (uint32_t)out[0] << 24 | out[1] << 16 | out[2] << 8 | out[3];`.

Comment: Try something like this at the end of the function to avoid problems with strict aliasing: `uint32_t result; memcpy(&result, out, sizeof result); return result;`.  Or use shifts with `|` to combine the 4 byte uint32_t from the four separate bytes in `out`. Or use the `-fno-strict-aliasing` option like Linux does.

Comment: These comments should be posted as answers

Comment: @mch it should be `unsigned char out[4]` to make that work

Comment: @MichaelBurr: Hrm, tried that, still no joy. Maybe it's something to do with the use of [`CFSwapInt32BigToHost()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFByteOrderUtils/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFSwapInt32BigToHost), which isn't in my example. `uint32_t result; memcpy(&result, out, sizeof result); return CFSwapInt32BigToHost(result);` still returning unexpected value. Value fine if I make `out` static.

Comment: What happens if you try it with a union?

Comment: Please post a small compilable example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis: Figured out the union syntax, `uint32_t result = *(uint32_t *)((union {char *a; uint32_t *b;})out).b;`. Result sadly the same. I expect 44, get 805306412.

Comment: Instead of putting the pointers in the union, can you try a union of the `char out[4]` and the `uint32_t` directly? In the function, declare `union { char out[4]; uint32_t num; } u;` then use `u.out` to fill the array and return `u.num`.

Comment: Use an `uint32_t` variable. Don't use `char[4]`. Manipulate bits of the `uint32_t` variable. FYI, the *most significant* byte of 805306412 is 44, so you likely have your endianness messed up, which is an additional argument against using casts, unions, aliases or any other non-portable stuff.

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis: Tried that, just returns 0. :-(

Comment: @n.m. Tried `uint32_t result; char *out = (char *)&result;` Still returns 805306412. Correctly returns 44 if I instead use `static uint32_t result;`. WTF? About to just surrender those 4 bytes to `static` and call it a night. Super frustrating.

Comment: @MichaelBurr: I've ben working on that, but can't get it to misbehave in a contained example. Grrr.

Comment: When `result` is static, value is 738197504 before passing to `CFSwapInt32BigToHost()`. When `result` is not static, it's 738197552 before passing to `CFSwapInt32BigToHost()` Only difference is use of `static` or not. o_O.

Comment: Show the entire function.

Comment: Okay, after a full day of debugging, I've discovered the bug. [Here's the full function](https://gist.github.com/theory/9fcb897eec374b4b46f4), in all its hideous glory. The bug, it turns out, is not a variable on the stack (this version has the `uint32_t` variable suggested by @n.m.). Rather, the bug is on line 49. Inside that while block, `i` can be 0, making `out[i-0]` go out of the array bounds. I switched from `<=` to `<` and the bug went away. No idea if this is technically correct for parsing AMF3 integers, I can find no other code like this.

Comment: Oh, and FWIW, it appears that Clang does the right thing with the wonky `return *(uint32_t *)out` syntax. I'm happy to dump it for greater clarity, though. And there are a bunch of correct answers in these comments, even if I turned out to have a different bug. I'd be happy to accept an answer, but would love to see all of them turned into answers.

Comment: Hey, how about moving comments to answers,  @mch et al.?